# How to save a binary file bigger than a DVD to a set of DVDs and how to recover them afterwards?

Tags: backup

how is it possible to save a file greater than 1 DVD to a set of DVDs 
14.8 GB and then how does one recover the file from the DVD set

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create an archive of the file. And allow the archive/compression utility split the file for you.

In Unity:

- right click on the file select compress
- click other options select a format that supports splitting an
  archive file into several
- click split into volumes and select the maximum size for each volume.

Then you can burn each file to your DVD.
You can just right click and select decompress once  you have copied the files over to the destination for it to reassemble all files.

Comment: The capacity of a normal DVD is 4.7 GB, the size of one chunk should be slightly smaller. Also you will want to test the integrity of the file with checksums: Run `md5sum original.file > original.md5` copy the file "orignal.md5" to the same folder as the deflated binary, then `md5sum -c orignal.md5`

Comment: tomodachi Did you mean nautilus

Comment: i am using 12.04 LTS server with Ubuntu-desktop

Comment: click other options select a format that supports splitting an archive file into several

Comment: the options are grayed out